# OS X Mavericks: mysql socket defined in my.cnf, but not getting created

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to install mysql5 (the latest from Oracle, via .dmg) on OS X Mavericks. My `/opt/local/my.cnf` looks like this:

```
[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[safe_mysqld] 
err-log=/var/log/mysqld.log 
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

When I try to connect, I get the following:

```
$ mysql5 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

And there is no `/tmp/mysql.sock` file created.

Here's my `/tmp` dir:

```
$ ls -l /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 24 08:31 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

I've also tried forcing the socket from the command line:

```
$ time sudo mysqld_safe5 --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
Password:
131221 07:26:02 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/Macintosh.local.err'.
131221 07:26:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
131221 07:17:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I know it's reading the conf file because if I remove it, I get a different socket location when I attempt to connect:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

But again, no luck. What do I need to do to get that socket created?

Comment: Apparently I had another mysql running which explained why it took mysqld_safe5 1m40s to start. Killing the other processes allows /tmp/mysql.sock to be created, but mysql5 still returns the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'`

Comment: After much research and trying the solutions below, I finally gave up and tried MacMiniVault's MySQL setup: https://github.com/MacMiniVault/Mac-Scripts/tree/master/mmvMySQL.

With that, my issues went away.

Answer (score 1):

Change your /tmp folder to have permission for MySQL user. (chown mysql:mysql /tmp or chmod 777 /tmp would resolve your issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using dtrace to see if mysqld is actually opening a socket, and if so, where.  You'll also be able to tell what config files are being read by the server, although that doesn't seem to be the issue since passing --socket=... doesn't work.

I'm used to strace on Linux but recently started using dtrace at work.  Here's a pretty simple example of how to trace open(2) calls, which you could modify to trace socket creation, or just all syscalls: https://github.com/tsibley/dtrace-scripts/blob/master/trace-open.d